# Area 51 follower count, where is myself?

Tags: bug, area-51, followers

I recently (yesterday) followed [*Health*](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health) and noticed that I'm not in the list of followers:
and the followers count is 19 which is exactly the number of user in that list (without me).
Am I missing something? (cached?)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Nope, not caching. I just followed [Coffee](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61013/coffee) and appear instantly in the list. Weird!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>I was able to reproduce with another account I have. **Looks like new account can't follow proposals**.</strike>

[Here is the link to the account profile page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/105845/shadow-of-the-shadow), showing it following the same proposal, but as in your case it's not "real" i.e. not showing anywhere else.

When trying with existing, old time account, all is working fine.

Mystery solved! When you register new account on Area 51 you should get such an email:

> ### Thanks for registering with Stack Exchange Area 51
>
> In order to follow proposals, we need to confirm your email address.
> All it takes is a single click.

Check you email, maybe it landed in the spam folder.

(note this applies also for users with accounts on other sites, since Area 51 stands on its own)

Comment: interesting, but this user [Jody](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/105737/jody) (4th in the list) is quite new, and he is in the list?? Or this problem is only happened from yesterday?

Comment: @Bolu true! Hmm... maybe OpenID issue... my new account use Stack Exchange, what's yours?

Comment: OpenID, Google Account?

Comment: @Bolu see my edit.

Comment: You are a star!